# Pandas - passing a custom aggregation function from configParser

Tags: python, pandas

with dataframe having data like below,

```
Time,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8,Col9,Col10,Col11,Col12,Col13
05:17:55.703,,,,,,21,,3,    89,891,11,
05:17:55.703,,,,,,21,,3,   217,891,12,
05:17:55.703,,,,,,21,,3,   217,891,13,
05:17:55.703,,,,,,21,,3,   217,891,15,
05:17:55.703,,,,,,21,,3,   217,891,16,
05:17:55.703,,,,,,21,,3,   217,891,17,
05:17:55.703,,,,,,21,,3,   217,891,18,
05:17:55.707,,,,,,18,,3,   185,892,0,
05:17:55.707,,,,,,21,,3,   185,892,1,
05:17:55.707,,,,,,17,,3,    73,892,5,
05:17:55.707,,,,,,17,,3,   185,892,6,
05:17:55.707,,,,,,21,,3,    73,892,7,
05:17:55.708,268,4,28,-67.60,13,,2,,,,,2
05:17:55.711,,,,,,18,,3,    57,892,10,
05:17:55.711,,,,,,21,,3,   201,892,11,
05:17:55.711,,,,,,21,,3,    25,892,12,
05:17:55.723,,,,,,21,,3,   217,893,11,
05:17:55.723,,,,,,21,,3,   217,893,15,
05:17:55.723,,,,,,21,,3,   217,893,16,
05:17:55.726,268,4,,-67.80,,,,,,,,
05:17:55.728,,,28,,12,31,2,3,   185,894,0,1
```

Need to do aggregation on each column with a different agg function. That is done like below.

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Time'])
d = {'Col2':'mean', 'Col3':'max', 'Col5':'median'}
df2 = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='40L', key='Time')).agg(d)
```

Now, for another column, say `Col1` I need to pass a custom mode function like below

```
def mode1(x):
    m = pd.Series.mode(x)
    return m.values[0] if not m.empty else np.nan
```

I can add `mode1` to the dictionary like below and the aggregation works.

```
aggDict = {'Col1': mode1, 'Col2':'mean', 'Col3':'max', 'Col5':'median'}
d = {'Col2':'mean', 'Col3':'max', 'Col5':'median'}
df2 = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='40L', key='Time')).agg(aggDict)
```

Further to this, I need read this dictionary from a config file so as to use it with different data frames with diff column names and agg methods respectively.

So I create a config file say `config.ini` like below and use it with `ConfigParser`

```
config.ini
[Config1]
# for PDSCH and CSF info Apex custom grid
Col1 = mode1
Col2 = mean
Col3 = max
Col4 = median
```

read the config file

```
from configparser import ConfigParser
cfgparser = ConfigParser()
cfgparser.optionxform = str # to keep case sensitive keys
cfgparser.read('config.ini')
aggDict = dict(cfgparser.items('Config1'))
```

When I pass the aggDict to `.agg()` function like `df2 = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='40L', key='Time')).agg(aggDict)` it complains `'SeriesGroupBy' object has no attribute 'mode1'`.

I know the problem here -it is that aggDict looks like below (and rightly so)

```
{'Col1': 'mode1',
 'Col2': 'mean',
 'Col3': 'max',
 'Col4': 'median'}
```

When `mode1` passed as a string, `SeriesGroupBy` cannot find it. How to go about this such that `SeriesGroupBy` can find the user defined `mode1` function when passed from `configParser` ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to call it from your globals or locals depending on the scope. So that would mean:

```
aggDict = {'Col1': globals()['mode1'], 'Col2':'mean', 'Col3':'max', 'Col5':'median'}
```

What you are doing is that you are calling a custom function to pass using the `globals()`. This is assuming that you have the function in the same class or file. When you parse it into the `aggDict` dictionary, use the format in the code above.

Comment: How to convert the `aggDict` which is `{'Col1': 'mode1',
 'Col2': 'mean',
 'Col3': 'max',
 'Col4': 'median'}` to what you have mentioned above programmatically.

Comment: update your dictionary before you pass it. `aggDict.update(Col1=globals()['mode1'])`  If you want to find the value and then update it, then you can use a loop which will look something like this `for key, value in aggDict.items(): if value == 'mode1' : aggDict[key] = globals()[value]`